# Magento 2 Add new Customer Attribute via UpgradeSchema

Tags: magento2, upgrade-script, upgradeschema

I have a module that has customer attributes added via the InstallSchema Script, however I have an UpgradeSchema script to also add more customer attributes;

Error below when running update in terminal;

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of 
  MyCompany\Extendedcustomer\Setup\UpgradeSchema::upgrade
  (Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
   Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context) 

     must be compatible with 

Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface::upgrade
 (Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup, 
  Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context) 

 in /app/code/MyCompany/Extendedcustomer/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php on line 17
```

Full Code:

```
<?php 

namespace MyCompany\Extendedcustomer\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{


protected $customerSetupFactory;

public function upgrade(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, 
    ModuleContextInterface $context
) {
    $setup->startSetup();

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {

        $setup->startSetup();

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
                'current_device',                    
                [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => 'Current Device',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'sort_order' => 300,
                    'position' => 400,
                    'default' => '',
                    'system' => false,
                    'is_used_in_grid' => 0,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => 1,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => 1,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => 1,
                ]
            );
        $Attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute( \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'current_device');
        $Attribute->setData(
        'used_in_forms',
            [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'customer_account_edit',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'adminhtml_customer_address',
                'customer_address_edit',
                'customer_register_address',
            ]
        );
        $Attribute->save();

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
                'current_scandevice',                    
                [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => 'Current RF Scan Device',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'sort_order' => 300,
                    'position' => 400,
                    'default' => '',
                    'system' => false,
                    'is_used_in_grid' => 0,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => 1,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => 1,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => 1,
                ]
            );
        $Attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute( \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'current_scandevice');
        $Attribute->setData(
        'used_in_forms',
            [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'customer_account_edit',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'adminhtml_customer_address',
                'customer_address_edit',
                'customer_register_address',
            ]
        );
        $Attribute->save();

        $setup->endSetup();

     }

   }
}
```

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/35427023/1423608

Comment: You should try in UpgradeData, not in UpgradeSchema :)

Comment: As @HimmatPaliwal said, use `UpgradeData` instead of `UpgradeSchema` because adding a new attribute will insert a new entry of data in the `eav_attributes` table not adding or altering the database schema

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try with below code if it works:

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\Extendedcustomer\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    private $attributeSetFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
                    'current_device',                    
                    [
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => 'Current Device',
                        'input' => 'text',
                        'required' => false,
                        'visible' => true,
                        'user_defined' => true,
                        'sort_order' => 1000,
                        'position' => 1000,
                        'system' => 0,
                    ]
                );
            $Attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'current_device')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => 1,
                'attribute_group_id' => 1,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','checkout_register', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit','adminhtml_checkout'],
            ]);

            $Attribute->save();

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'current_scandevice', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Current RF Scan Device',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 1000,
                'position' => 1000,
                'system' => 0,
            ]);

            $Attribute2 = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'current_scandevice')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => 1,
                'attribute_group_id' => 1,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','checkout_register', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit','adminhtml_checkout'],
            ]);

            $Attribute2->save();

        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Please let me know in case still it creates issue.

Comment: Thankyou @Himmat  +1

Comment: Welcome anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

DO it by InstallData.
Way I prefere
**app/code/vendor/moduel/Setup/InstallData.php**

```
    <?php

namespace Vendor/Moduel\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, Config $eavConfig)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'sample_attribute',
            [
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => 'Sample Attribute',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'required'     => false,
                'visible'      => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'position'     => 999,
                'system'       => 0,
            ]
        );
        $sampleAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'sample_attribute');

        // more used_in_forms ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address']
        $sampleAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer']

        );
        $sampleAttribute->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already run InstallSchema, module is in upgrading level

Comment: What happens when I have already run InstallData but have new attributes to add via version changes ..